# How to close a crashed Visual Studio debugger?

Tags: debugging, crash, visual-studio-2013, fullscreen

I feel pretty ridiculous having to ask this, but is there an easy way to close Visual Studio while it's debugging?

I'm debugging my application, and when switching to full screen it crashes. I am unable to alt-tab to visual studio to stop the debugger, and I'm unable to pull any other windows on top of the full screen application.

I can, however, see the start bar. I can right click on visual studio and click close, but it does nothing (same goes for the debugging application).

I'm unable to get the task manager to show in front of the full screen application.. However, I'm on Windows 8 and I've noticed the Metro interface still works (and all metro apps). If I could find a little command prompt metro app I'm sure I could get around this, but I'm unable to.

Is there an easier way to resolve the issue without having to restart my pc each time I crash?

Almost forgot to mention, I'm on Visual Studio 2013

Edit: Forgot to mention, I'm programming on-the-go on a laptop; I only have the one monitor for this situation

Comment: Two monitors is an absolutely essential asset.  Keep VS in one, the app in the other.

Comment: I completely agree, but I'm at my University on a small Microsoft Surface

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to use Developer Command Prompt - see [MDbg.exe (.NET Framework Command-Line Debugger)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229861%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to debug and kill your process

Comment: Thanks, I will look into a way to do this. I might be able to pin it to my start bar and run it from there when stuck in full screen

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution:

I can toggle focus to Visual Studio via Windows' Alt-Tab hotkey. This won't bring up Visual Studio, though.

Usually the problem is an unhandled exception, which requires me to hit "break." Since I gave Visual Studio focus, I can hit enter to select break.

I then use the Shift+F5 hotkey to stop the debugger